# unable to get a list of elements from xml page

Tags: python, automation, android-uiautomator

I need to find if some entry in the list is checked and uncheck it.
I'am using uiautomator to do it.I'am looping on list this way:

```
for box  in device_obj(className="android.widget.LinearLayout"):
..
```

The problem is that there are several other objects with the same class name.
So i'am giving the  path starting with the list member:

```
  for box  in device_obj(className="android.widget.ListView").child(
    className="android.widget.LinearLayout"):
..
```

to my suprise i get only first list member - 'Show Hints' !
why is this?
Can't I get list of elements when path consists of 2 or more elements?

this is the screen and xml screenshot:
[image: this is xml of android screen]

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
element = find_elements(:xpath, //android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.ListView).map
```